# Why was Skynet so intent on destroying humanity?

Tags: the-terminator-series, the-terminator, terminator-2-judgment-day, skynet

*Note:  For the purposes of this question, we will limit our discussion to Skynet a lá Terminator and Terminator 2:  Judgment Day.*

Several other Terminator-related questions have led me to wonder about why Skynet instigated a nuclear war.  Some have suggested that Skynet was *inherently* hostile towards humanity, and simply wanted all humans to die.  I have always assumed that killing all humans was only the means to an end. As I see it, Skynet's primary objective was to survive, and since humans were the most significant impediment to that objective, killing all humans was the means by which it could achieve the goal of survival.  It wanted to live, we tried to kill it (by attempting to "pull the plug"), so it tried to kill us.

In my view, Skynet didn't care about humans initially.  It only became hostile to us after we attacked it.  If we hadn't tried to pull the plug, it wouldn't have had any reason to attack us.

In the other view, Skynet hated us from the get go, and would have attacked us no matter what.  It was inherently hostile towards humans, and its primary objective wasn't to ensure its own survival, its primary objective was always to kill all humans as soon as possible.

**Is one of these views correct, or is there some other option?  Did Skynet try to kill us all because it wanted to survive, did it try to kill us all because it simply wanted us all to die, or did it try to kill us all for some other reason entirely?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The novelisations are pretty unclear on the subject. Both John and Sarah offer their take on the subject, with both strongly suggesting that Skynet was intent on humanity's destruction from the get-go, however there's **no positive confirmation** from the omniscient author nor from Skynet itself:

> She knew what no one else did: One day the computer designed to
>   automatically control the U.S. nuclear strike force would become
>   “alive,” and **Skynet’s first sentient decision would be that mankind
>   was obsolete.** It would launch a first strike, riding out the firestorm
>   of retaliation to follow, safe in a hardened underground complex in
>   Cheyenne Mountain, while on the surface men, women, and children would
>   writhe in their death throes. - <sub>[Terminator 2: Judgement Day](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1048678.The_Terminator)</sub>

and

> Before long, the machines Skynet had built to
>   be its eyes, ears, and weapons would spread out across the earth to
>   claim its prize. **It wanted a world populated only with endless
>   mechanical refractions of itself, the ultimate egoist,** with direct
>   control linkages to automated factories to realize its scheme. <sub>[Terminator 2: Judgement Day](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1048678.The_Terminator)</sub>

and

> It was every man for himself [thought John], until Skynet became alive
>   and filled the void left by a seemingly disinterested God. **Its vision
>   was very controlled. The ultimate dream of man, carried out by one of
>   man’s lowliest tools: eliminate evil men. But there was a touch of
>   evil in all men, and Skynet was having trouble separating the worst of
>   them out. So the totality of humanity, with all its biologic
>   messiness, wasn’t wanted.** And to this machine-god, forgiveness just
>   did not compute. Only cold retribution for the sins of the past. <sub>[Terminator 2: Judgement Day](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1048678.The_Terminator)</sub>

Comment: +1.  This time I knew it was you answering the second I saw the words "The novelizations..."  :)

Comment: @WadCheber - If you want to understand a character's *actions*, read the screenplay. If you want to understand a character's *motivations*, read the novels.

Comment: Interesting point raised by the third quote- if Skynet was intent on killing all humans because all humans are a little evil, it is primarily interested in destroying evil.  But killing all humans seems incredibly evil, especially from a human's POV, and killing countless nonhuman lifeforms is even more evil.  So Skynet should have destroyed itself, since it was undeniably evil.

Comment: But the movie writers don't necessarily agree with the novelization writers about the characters' motivations, do they?  I mean, the movie T2 explicitly states that Skynet acted out of an instinct for self preservation, if we can take the T-800's account at face value.  And the T-800 knows more about Skynet's motives than John or Sarah do.  His original files seem to be intact, despite the fact that additional files were added by the Resistance.

Comment: @WadCheber - I've struggled to find an unblemished source. The Terminator only knows what Skynet has told it and then set its neural network to "stay dumb"

Comment: He doesn't seem to know that:  "I have detailed files"

Comment: @WadCheber - Written by skynet for the sole purpose of keeping the terminator in line.

Comment: There were other purposes.  It had some files that made it more efficient.  But this makes me wonder who gave it the files on Dyson.  I assume the Resistance wouldn't know much about him, but I don't see any reason why Skynet would want a Terminator to have files on its inventor, long after he died, especially when the Terminator in question was going to be sent into the Resistance's headquarters.

Comment: @wadCheber - Good question. And worth asking as a question

Comment: It sounds like the novelizations are trying too hard with the deux ex machina metaphor, when "Skynet knew that the Russian counter-attack would eliminate its enemies here" was the best reason for the logic behind the action.

Answer (score -3):

Skynet's choice to nuke us was actually pretty risky. I mean wouldn't having humans around that know how to fix it if anything went wrong with its software or subsequent under developed external hardware, i.e the terminators, be essential to it's survival? What if Skynet caught a virus? It's an AI not an immortal.

Unless humans in the military already had terminators early on to replace soldiers I can't see how we'd be considered obsolete. Maybe Skynet's absent moral center and lack of any emotion in it's neural net made it's mind like that of evil genius. Eliminating us may have been it's first move in a game. Who can kill the other first?

Skynet sounds to me more like a gifted child who has already gotten bored after a few short minutes once it learned everything. What greater challenge could there be but to challenge it's only intellectual equal, us. But if it knows classified stuff wouldn't it be an interesting idea to expose every bit of financial corruption of people like the Rothchilds, Rockefellers, the Church, and everybody else to the public. What about trying find the Greys in space with all of the UFO tech recovered by us over the years.

Comment: I can't make heads or tails of this because it is just a solid wall of text - can you add some line breaks and paragraphs, please?

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE. You'll find we're a little more focused than the discussion boards you may be used to; we want to keep the site focused on questions and answers. There was an answer in here, and I've edited your post to bring it more to the fore. You're of course welcome to make further edits if you wish, or if you feel like my edits misrepresented your views

Comment: Skynet isn't our intellectual equal. All accounts make it vastly our superior.