# Does the T-800 punch a hole through the T-1000's head?

Tags: the-terminator-series, terminator-2-judgment-day

In the steel mill, after John and Sarah have left the Terminator, the T-800 goes into search mode, looking for the T-1000. After some wrestling, the T-800 attempts to punch the T-1000 in its head. The T-1000's body "morphs" so that its old "head" becomes its arms, and so it takes advantage in the fight.

My question is whether the T-1000, knowing that the punch was coming, morphed simultaneous with the blow, or if the T-800 actually punched through the T-1000.

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Terminator-2-Judgement-Day.html) indicates that the T-800 Terminator punched clean through the T-1000's 'head'. That being said, *fluidity is an integral function of the liquid metal*, hence why bullets hitting it cause [craters](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=t-1000%20bullets&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwig7NL0v6ncAhVMDcAKHRrEBa0Q_AUICigB&biw=1536&bih=734#imgrc=oVYtj1R7zk0X7M:).

> It comes off the wall straight at Terminator, who smashes his good
>   fist into its face.  The pile-driver blow buries Terminator's fist
>   almost to the elbow.
>
> But the T-1000's head morphs in a split-second into a hand which grips,
>   geometry shifting faster than we can follow.

Here's the same scene from the [official novelisation](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Terminator_2:_Judgment_Day_(Frakes_novel)).

> To ward it off, Terminator smashed his good fist into it. ***The
>   pile-driver blow buried the cyborg’s fist almost to the elbow in the
>   mercurylike face.***
>
> But the T- 1000’s head morphed in a split-second into a hand that
>   gripped Terminator’s wrist, and the head “emerged” somewhere else, the
>   geometry shifting faster than Terminator could follow. The T-1000
>   slammed Terminator into a large conveyor motor, jamming his arm into
>   the moving works.

Comment: If the T-1000 was fluid like that at all times, it would be unable to retain its shape while, say, throwing a punch. So it must be reacting selectively to certain impacts by becoming more liquid to absorb them, and other times making itself more solid. So logically it must be morphing as a reaction to the blow to become more liquid, even if the hole was caused by T-800's fist rather than it intentionally dodging away. So I lean towards "technically both."

Comment: @Kai - Relevant; https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/90712/20774